# I can't get the first string using sharedPreferences android studio

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm working with sharedpreferences and I can put names in the .xml file, the problem is when I try to get only the first name name
ins this case I can see:
D/mySharedPref: [alan, lyneth, daniel, oscar] but I want to see only alan how can I get the name that I'm asking

```
String id = "1";
for(int i = 0; i<getListValueFromKey.size(); i++){
    Log.d("mySharedPref", ""+getListValueFromKey); 
    //in the log window show this:
    //  D/mySharedPref: [alan, lyneth, daniel, oscar]
    }
```

Comment: Rather than using a for-loop to iterate through the set (I assume you're fetching these values from a set), you should use an iterator instead. You can simply get the nth element afterwards. I'll try to post an answer soon.

Comment: ok thank you, this is how my XML is build: <set name="myFields">
        <string>lyneth</string>
        <string>oscar</string>
        <string>daniel</string>
        <string>alan</string>
    </set> and I using new HashSet<String>()); to .add my info because is the only way that I get that the xml dosn't rewrite I mean with this I add new <strings> o the xml

Comment: Thank you I got it:

//add to an Array 
        Object[] resourceArray = getListValueFromKey.toArray();
        
        int i;

        //I put in the log the first name 
        Log.d("myName", ""+resourceArray[1]);

        //I log the names inside the array 
        for(i = 0; i<resourceArray.length; i++){
            Log.d("mySharedPref", ""+resourceArray[i]);

        }

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is the way I resolved the problem:

```
//add to an Array 
        Object[] resourceArray = getListValueFromKey.toArray();


//I preferred to leave this var outside to manipulate after 
        int i;

        //I put in the log the first name 
        Log.d("myName", ""+resourceArray[1]);

        //I log the names inside the array 
        for(i = 0; i<resourceArray.length; i++){
            Log.d("mySharedPref", ""+resourceArray[i]);

        }
```